# C# - Using WPF to create a Two-line ListBox for each item

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, multiline

Im having some trouble with WPF, as its my first time usage of it.

Im trying to create a ListBox, that holds two lines for each item in it. How can i achieve this ?

I have tried the following:

```
<ListBox>
    <Label name="first">First Line</label>
    <Label name="second">Second Line</label>
</ListBox>
```

Even though this does not give any errors, i do not think its the correct way to do it.

Can you guys assist ?

Comment: I think you need to add ListBoxItem not a label.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by modifying the `ListBox` `ItemTemplate`, while binding to a collection of data you want to display.

Xaml:

```
<ListBox Name="MyListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxData}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text1}" MinWidth="200"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text2}" MinWidth="200"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Xaml.cs:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow 
    {
        public List<MyRow> ListBoxData { get; set; } 
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            ListBoxData = new List<MyRow>
            {
                new MyRow{Text1 = "Row 1 - Data 1", Text2 = "Row 1 - Data 2"},
                new MyRow{Text1 = "Row 2 - Data 1", Text2 = "Row 2 - Data 2"},
                new MyRow{Text1 = "Row 3 - Data 1", Text2 = "Row 3 - Data 2"}
            };
        }
    }       

    public class MyRow
    {
        public string Text1 { get; set; }
        public string Text2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In terms of WPF, you typically want to use binding rather than hard-coding items into the xaml directly. The example above shows data binding via code-behind, but ideally, you would want to create a ViewModel and bind to that. I would suggest looking up MVVM once you get more familiar w/ WPF.

Answer (score 0):

You can create items in a list box like so,

```
<ListBox>
     <ListBoxItem Name="Item1">Item</ListBoxItem>
     <ListBoxItem Name="Item2">Item2</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Or if you want them dynamically assigned you can set the value like so in code,

```
Listbox1.ItemsSource = <some collection>;
Listbox1.DisplayMemberPath = "<Collection item you want displayed>";
```

Or this way for MVVM pattern

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=<Your Property>}" DisplayMemeberPath="{Binding Path =Display Value Property}" />
```